# Is it possible to close php tags and reopen them in the middle of a foreach loop?

Tags: php

I'm processing information from a database in php, and intend to set values in a html code block:

```
$var = [function to grab multiple rows from database]($args);
foreach ($var as $row) {
echo "<p>$row[username]</p>";
}
```

The problem is the code in that echo statement isn't a simple `<p></p>`, but about 50 lines of html. Is it possible to close the php tags in the middle of the foreach loop, like so:

```
    $var = [function to grab multiple rows from database]($args);
    foreach ($var as $row) {
?>
<p> <?php echo "$row[username]";?> </p>
<?php
    }
?>
```

And if not, what do you suggest?

Comment: Yes, what you have there should work exactly as is

Comment: Excellent! PHP really is an impressive language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** You can do that....

```
<?php
 foreach ($var as $row) {
?>
<p> <?php echo "$row[username]";?> </p>
<!--you can write any html you like-->
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this annotation:

```
<?php foreach ($var as $row): ?>
    <p> <?=$row[username] ?> </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

PD: you don't need wrap a single var with quotes in the echo

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd recommend the following style (use of shorttags is optional based on intended install environment. see below)

```
<? foreach ($var as $row) : ?>
    <p><?= $row[username] ?></p>
<? endforeach ?>
```

The use of `<?` is only advisable if you fully control the PHP config in the environments you run in (e.g. you yourself run the only installation of your software).

If you're distributing your software broadly (like wordpress, etc.) and absolute compatibility is desired (e.g. your code is both PHP 4 AND PHP 5 compatible, and your code is running on various $5/month shared accounts, etc.) then avoiding short tags is strongly recommended.

`<?=` is supported universally as of PHP 5.4 -- but again, if you have users installing your code on their own servers, you can't count on them having PHP 5.4 available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The code example you've provided will work.

PHP even supplies us with alternative syntax to improve readability:

```
    $var = [function to grab multiple rows from database]($args);
    foreach ($var as $row) :
?>
<p> <?php echo "$row[username]";?> </p>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
```